# Enable Multiple Downloads Chrome Headless Selenium Python without original File replacement

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a command or argument that downloads multiple files with same name without deleting the file(file with same name) using chrome headless in Selenium Python?

I want to download multiple files with same name without replacing any of them.How do i enable this in headless Chrome +Selenium+Python?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a browser-based approach?  Why not `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: Its a JS Page that needs to be clicked before file being downloaded.Plus the content lies inside an iframe.So its not possible with wget.Otherwise program would have been simpler with requests or wget module.

Comment: Thanks all for your support.After some hardwork and research ,I managed to find the answer. How should I close this question?

Comment: Hi @Akshay what was the solution by the way?

Comment: Hi! It's late but I'm having the same problem. Could you share your answer @Akshay?